# Drupal 8 - how to access field values nested deep inside an array structure

Tags: arrays, twig, drupal-8, kint

I am trying to access values of a content type nested deep into array. This is the actual scenario:

I want to customise the default search result page layout of Drupal 8 with additional field information. To know what fields are available for me to access I used `{{ kint(item.value) }}`, which shows me this:

[image]

Fields I want to access are nested under **`#result>node>fields`** like `body`, `field_category` etc.

Is there any way I can access them directly inside my twig template? I was guessing something like `{{ item.value['node']['fields']['field_name']} }`? but this gave me nothing!

There is every possibility that the way I am thinking is not a suitable method or may be even not a method at all! I am still very new to Drupal.

All I want is to **access desired fields nested deep below inside an array structure**. Is there a kind of thumb rule or syntax to follow? Is there a process to access a specific element from inside a nested Drupal array?

Note: In order to customise layout I copied `item-list.html.twig` file from `/core/themes/stable/templates/dataset` to my theme's templates folder.

**Drupal version: 8.2.3**

### Edit

Template file for search result (`item-list.html.twig`)

```
<p class="righteous">Makes sure the page is being hit!</p>

{% if context.list_style %}
    {%- set attributes = attributes.addClass('item-list__' ~ context.list_style) %}
{% endif %}
{% if items or empty %}
    {%- if title is not empty -%}
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    {%- endif -%}

    {%- if items -%}
        <{{ list_type }}{{ attributes }}>
        {%- for item in items -%}
            <li{{ item.attributes }}>{{ content.body }}</li>
        {%- endfor -%}
        </{{ list_type }}>
    {%- else -%}
        {{- empty -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endif %}
```

Comment: cannot find any errors. my editor syntax highlight just the </{{ list_type }}> red. you checked if the IF statment is true? and ive never seen those minuses in {%- -%}.

Comment: I don't have any idea what those "-" signs are doing. I copied the template from stable theme and it was written there like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render specific fields from a template you have to use for example:

```
{{ content.field_feature }}
```

you can see in your array or in the UI of d8 the machine names of your fields.

```
{{ content.field_<machine-name> }}
```

with this you can access your array and theme your content type yourself.

Comment: I tried `{{ content.body }}` and `{{ content.field_category }}` but nothing was displayed. As far as `kint` shows I don't see an element named `content`.

Comment: @SubrataSarkar did you try to write easy html into your template to check if d8 use this template?

Comment: Yes, I already did that and made sure that this is "the" page.

Comment: @SubrataSarkar can you show me your template file? maybe you miss some essential elements

Comment: Hi, I have edited updated my question with template file Html.